# How to add an image to the left or right of a new form(issue tracking list)?

Tags: custom-form, newform

I'm pretty new at sharepoint and have been tasked with using it to create a helpdesk system, now i've manage to read and teach myself everything i've needed so far(thanks to this site and a couple others) but for the life of me i can't figure out how to add an image to preferably the right of a new form for an issue tracking list.

Hopefully i've used the right terminology explaining this but i have linked to a screenshot of what im talking about.

I think my org is running SP2010 but could be 2013.

Thank in advance for any help you can provide.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enough permissions you should be able to edit the page and add a Content Editor and add the html for an image tag.

You could also use SharePoint Designer and edit the New Form for that list.

You can add a table around the existing code and then in the next table data (td) you can add the image tag. e.g:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Existing Code for the form
    </td>
    <td>
      <img>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks very much! the (td) was the answer to resolving it. was staring me in the face the whole time.